# Does the Visual Studio Test Runner Support Other Frameworks?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

Can I run nUnit tests in Visual Studio (for instance)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get TestDriven.NET.  This add-in for Visual Studio supports the following test frameworks:

```
NUnit
MbUnit
ZaneBug
MSTest
NCover
NCoverExplorer
Reflector
TypeMock
dotTrace
MSBee
```

The "personal" version is free.

Answer (score 0):

No. But [Testdriven.NET](http://www.testdriven.net/) supports the internal tests and many others.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. See [Visual Studio Support](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=vsSupport&r=2.5) in the NUnit documentation:

> Visual Studio support in this release
>   is a sort of “poor man’s integration.”
>   We have implemented a number of
>   features while avoiding any that would
>   require using an Addin or otherwise
>   interacting with the Visual Studio
>   extensibility model.

Also, FYI, ReSharper has a test runner that can run NUnit tests inside of Visual Studio.